# sympyで「AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'subs'」がでました。

Tags: python, sympy

文字列'x-y'をx-yに変換する方法を教えて下さい。

```py
from sympy import *
var('x y')
print(type( x-y ),( x-y ).subs(x,0.0))
print(type('x-y'))
print(type('x-y'),('x-y').subs(x,0.0))
# <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'> -y
# <class 'str'>
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "C:/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 5, in <module>
#     print(type('x-y'),('x-y').subs(x,0.0))
# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'subs'
```

Comment: これあたりでしょうか。[sympyで文字列を直接数式として扱いたい(sympifyを使う)](https://esu-ko.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/06/18/sympy%E3%81%A7%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%82%92%E7%9B%B4%E6%8E%A5%E6%95%B0%E5%BC%8F%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E6%89%B1%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%28sympify%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sympy import *
var('x y')
print("# ",type( x-y ),( x-y ).subs(x,0.0))
print("# ",type('x-y'))
print("# ",type(sympify('x-y')),sympify('x-y').subs(x,0.0))
#  <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'> -y
#  <class 'str'>
#  <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'> -y
```